# Detect Excel Event Cell Format Change

Tags: c#, excel-2010, excel-addins

I am creating an Excel Add-In in C# using Visual Studio 2010 and trying to detect when a cell's formatting is changed.  I can detect when the content of the cell changes using

```
Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler(myListener);
```

but the event doesn't seem to be firing when I bold the text in a cell, or put a border around the cell.